# Invalid manifest Version

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest

I built and deployed a sample application on chrome webstore with default version number 1.0

But when I tried to update the same extension. It gives me the following error
`The manifest has an invalid version: “2.0”. Please format the version as defined.`

I updated the version number in the manifest.json file as shown [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/version.html)

I tried "1.1", "1.1.1", "2.0", "1.1.1.1", "1.1.2.23". None of them seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was due to character. Had to change the quotation symbol from `“` to `"`

Answer (score 0):

Another reason may be caused this error, if you don't have tag in your git.

You might need to do:

```
$ git tag 0.1.0
$ git push origin --tags
```